# I can only edit a page in Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a New Page from Master in SharePoint Designer using a custom master page. I can open the page and edit it freely in Designer, but when I open the page in the browser, it treats it like a webpart page, meaning I cannot add anything unless I have a webpart zone. I would rather not use webpart zones, because I would like my users to be able to move things around later. Is there some way to make SharePoint treat my new pages more like wikipages? Or is there a setting I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear from your question, although seems like you are asking about creating/editing new page in Sharepoint using SharePoint designer.
Follow the below link, hope it will help

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-sharepoint-site-pages-HA101782505.aspx

Comment: I have read through that before, but thank you. My problem is that pages made from master pages are webpart pages, not wikipages and I would like to change that.